# Text not displaying on routing

Tags: angular

I am building a sample program in Angular 11 in which i have an **app** component and a **Show** component. In app component there are two buttons **English** & **Japanese** which on click navigate to **Show Component ** & displays the text in English/Japanese (depending on the button click)in **App Component**.

**Problem:** The problem is when i click on either Japanese or English button, it gets navigated to **Show** component and display the text in language(ex: English) but when i click the Japanese button it does nothing. In console, it showing the language as Japanese but on front end it is showing nothing.

**app.component.html**

```
<h4>App Component</h4>
<button (click)="showComponent('English')">English</button>
<button (click)="showComponent('Japanese')">Japanese</button>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { LanguageService } from './language.service';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'DataSharedService';
  constructor(public router: Router, public languageService: LanguageService) {}
  showComponent(selectedLanguage: string): void {
    console.log(selectedLanguage);
    this.languageService.checkLanguage(selectedLanguage);
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/show').then(r => console.log(r));
  }
}
```

**show.component.html**

```
<p>{{currLanguage}}</p>
<h4 *ngIf="currLanguage=='English'">You selected English !</h4>
<h4 *ngIf="currLanguage=='Japanese'">日本語を選びました！</h4>
```

**show.component.ts**

```
import { LanguageService } from './../language.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-show',
  templateUrl: './show.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./show.component.scss']
})
export class ShowComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public languageService: LanguageService) { }
  currLanguage = '';
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.currLanguage = this.languageService.language;
    console.log('Inside Show Component , current language is : ' + this.currLanguage);
  }
}
```

**language.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LanguageService {
  language = '';
  constructor() {}
  checkLanguage(selectedLanguage: string) {
    this.language = selectedLanguage;
    return this.language;
  }
}
```

**Snapshot**
On Clicking English the data gets displayed but on clicking Japanese nothing happens

[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgsSv.png)

**Any solution please ?**

Comment: In show.component.html, <p>{{currLanguage}}</p> prints Japanese ?

Comment: Ali Tahir: It will display only for one button for example if you click on Japanese first it will display japanese language but if you select english nothing will happens, you have to then refresh the page again and click on English button to display the text in English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you visit the show component it will not refresh the same component by clicking on buttons

Just replace your `showComponent` method to refresh the same route

```
showComponent(selectedLanguage: string): void {
    console.log(selectedLanguage);
    this.languageService.checkLanguage(selectedLanguage);

    this.router.navigateByUrl('/', { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['/show']);
    });
  }
```

it will refresh your show component on button click

Comment: user5239222: Thank you brother, your solution worked for me. Have a nice day . Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose **navigateByUrl** method doesn't update show component, because you are already staying on the same page. I would prefer to use subjects here.
Modify your **language.service.ts** like this:

```ts
export class LanguageService {
  private langSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  language$: Observable<string> = this.langSubject.asObservable();
  checkLanguage(selectedLanguage: string) {
    this.langSubject.next(selectedLanguage);
  }
}
```

and **show.component.html**:

```html
<p>{{currLanguage | async}}</p>
```